# jQuery Get the Name Attribute of a Sibillings First Child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML Structure

```
<form action="todo.php" method="post" name="todo">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input name="checklist[0]" type="text">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input name="checklist[0][task][]" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
          <input name="checklist[0][task][]" type="text">
        </li>
      </ul>
      <a class="add" href="todo.php">Add one</a> </li>
    <li>
      <input name="checklist[1]" type="text">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input name="checklist[1][task][]" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
          <input name="checklist[1][task][]" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
          <input name="checklist[1][task][]" type="text">
        </li>
      </ul>
      <a class="add" href="todo.php">Add one</a> </li>
    <li>
      <input name="checklist[2]" type="text">
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <a class="add" href="todo.php">Add one</a> </li>
  </ul>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$( ".add" ).click(function() {

  // Find the Task Count
  var task_count = $(this).siblings('ul').children('li').length;
  var task_name = $(this).siblings('ul').children('li').attr("name");
  var input = '<li><input name="checklist[][task][]" type="text"></li>';

  console.log(task_count);
  console.log(task_name);

  $(this).siblings('ul').append(input);

  return false;
});
```

When i click Add i want to get the Sibilling `UL`'s first Child's `NAME` Attribute

In the Above code's

```
var task_name = $(this).siblings('ul').children('li').attr("name");
```

This seems to throw back `undefined`

Comment: can you print task_count ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(this).siblings('ul').children('li').attr("name")
```

This will throw `undefined` as `li` elements are not having any `name` attribute

you need to do ths :-

```
  $(this).siblings('ul').children('li').find('input').attr("name")
```

**OR**

```
  $(this).siblings('ul').children('li').children('input').attr("name")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this : You are trying to get `name` attribute of `li`, instead find `input` inside `li` and then get its `name` attribute

```
var task_name = $(this).siblings('ul').children('li:first').find('input').attr("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var task_name = $(this).parents("li:first").find("input[name]:first").attr('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are trying to do the `dom manipulation` is wrong. You are actually targeting the `li` element in your code, but the requirement is to grab the `input` element present inside of that `li`. So you should use `.find()` to search for the descendants inside of that `li`.

Try,

```
var task_name = $(this).siblings('ul').children('li:first').find("input").attr('name');
```